# Routing from one 1 page to another in Angular app

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a basic example to work and can't. I have created a new Angular app and used the CLI to generate a new page called `qr-code`. I have then added a button to the homepage called `qr-code` which I would like to link to the `qr-code` page. The code is:

```html
<ion-button>
    <ion-icon name="qr-code-outline" routerLink='/qr-code'></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Link to QR Code</ion-label>
</ion-button>
```

The button is clickable but the `routerLink` is not working. Is there something else I should be adding somewhere?

##### app-routing.module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'qr-code',
    loadChildren: () => import('./qr-code/qr-code.module').then( m => m.QrCodePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

##### qr-code-app-routing.module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { QrCodePage } from './qr-code.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: QrCodePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class QrCodePageRoutingModule {}
```

##### qr-code.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { QrCodePageRoutingModule } from './qr-code-routing.module';

import { QrCodePage } from './qr-code.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    QrCodePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [QrCodePage]
})
export class QrCodePageModule {}
```

Comment: can you please share qr-code.routing.module.ts file and qr-code.module.ts file code?

Comment: thanks Aman for looking at it, have included the files

Comment: Can you please confirm your QrCodePageModule  module file name is qr-code.module.ts or qr-code-page.module.ts?

Comment: it is qr-code.module.ts thanks

Comment: can you please create stackblitz so I will try and run code?

Comment: home routes works perfectly?

Comment: I have checked your code. Look's like perfact. I don't know why it's not working

Comment: Can you please try with removed { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules } this from app-routing.module.ts file?

Comment: thanks for looking Aman, tried loading to Stackblitz but wouldn't load! Have removed the { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules } but same result unfortunately, button doesn't route to qr-code page

Comment: routerLink='/qr-code' this link please add in the ion-button.

Comment: @Jon When you tap on button it's navigate to home page?

Comment: many thanks Aman for the help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<ion-button routerLink='/qr-code'>
<ion-icon name="qr-code-outline"></ion-icon>
<ion-label>Link to QR Code</ion-label>
</ion-button>
```

I think your `routerLink` should be on the `ion-button` attribute instead of `ion-icon`